# Django Debug Toolbar - Which version has the green panel that docks at the top?

Tags: django

I turned on my debug toolbar and was surprised to see the stock template where the panels are aligned to the right.

I upgraded to django 1.3 and re-installed most of my requirements via PIP, which is where I imagine my usual toolbar disappeared.

I had always thought it was David Cramer's fork that had the green panel bar docked at the top, which I find insanely more usable (doesn't obstruct anything), plus it had some default default panels like unique SQL counts.

Now that I've cloned both [David's fork](https://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar) and [Rob's original](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar), I see neither have this green dock.

Am I going insane? Is this a setting I've missed, or perhaps a different fork? I would kill for the workflow I'm used to!

**Update:** I've looked through the commits, and indeed, there was a version in 2009 that was docked at the top, but had nowhere near the functionality that the version I'm talking about had. The exact commit that moved the toolbar to the right appears to be: https://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar/commit/565b100f9d97214043ae93c51d276951a65331e8

But nowhere can I find this awesome version below:

It also claims to be version 0.2 which I find odd too. I will keep going through each commit but any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It used to have the bar at the top. The new version has the new sidebar layout.

Update:
I tried to find out which version it was, but found this page where you can download older versions.

https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/downloads

**Update2**:

Here is the commit where he moves to the side panel 8-11-2009. Yeah a long time ago. I guess it has been a while since I upgraded as well :)

https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/commit/565b100f9d97214043ae93c51d276951a65331e8

Comment: When? Was it on David's fork only or both? I'm going back to various commits but do not see this. Wow, if I go back to 2009, there's an Orange version at the top ;) I guess my version was older than I thought? I will keep digging through the commits